# codeigniter 4 password_verify can not works

Tags: codeigniter

I am using password_hash function to store password in table it works but can not give result after password_verify what is mistake done my me.

```
'password'=>password_hash($this->request->getPost('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT),

$users=new UsersModel();
                $email=$this->request->getPost('email');
                $password=$this->request->getPost('password');
                $result=$users->where('email',$email)->first();

                $get_password=$result['password'];

                if(!password_verify($password,$get_password))
                {
                    return redirect()->to(base_url('admin/login'))->with('failed','Password is not matched');
                
                }
                else
                {
                     $user_id=$result['id'];
                    session()->set('loguser',$user_id);
                    return redirect()->to(base_url('/admin'));
                }
```

Comment: What error appears?

Comment: not error .. all records on single page no pagination works